# Requirement to compare the BDD Test cases to the crawled page objects and map the bdd steps to page objects and pages automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am creating a Keras based nueral networking on top of Tensorflow. My requirement is to take 2 data sets as below and compare

1. Take the test steps as first input as a sentence for a website
2. Get the crawled objects and pages for a web site

Then using Keras and Tensor flow pass both inputs.

Convert

a) to NLP based output after cleansing and objects also cleanse it. Both need to be passed to the neuron to find the similairty. Outcome should be similarity.

Pls advise how do we do it. Basic idea is based on test case it should tell which page and object is taking about

1. Moved page and objects to the pandas data frame cleansed it and it became as below
2. Take the test cases which is as below in pandas data frame
   now both the inputs are passed to Keras Embedding as Tensors.

Next done cosine similarity.

Next fit that model in loop for each of records cosinesimilarity.Words like personal details etc I made my own corpus as personal details firstname ,personal details lastname etc

Pls advise when fitting it is giving shape issue if it do directly and hence has to pass it in loop for each record. is this correct or what is correct approach

Comment: steps
open the open cart url
click register 
enter personal details
enter address details
click submit to register

Comment: pagename  objectname xpath 
login     email      input(text()="email")
login     password   input(text()="password")
login     submit     button(text()="submit")
register  firstname  input(text()="firstname")
register  lastname   input(text()="lastname") 
register  address1   input(text()="address1")
register  address2   input(text()="address2")
register  submit     button(text="register")

Comment: Final outcome should be like

Comment: pagename  objectname xpath 
login     email      input(text()="email")
login     password   input(text()="password")
login     submit     button(text()="submit")
register  firstname  input(text()="firstname")
register  lastname   input(text()="lastname") 
register  address1   input(text()="address1")
register  address2   input(text()="address2")
register  submit     button(text="register")

Comment: Add the information of outcomes to your question.

Comment: Outcomes are similairty of this 2 data sets one of BDD Test cases and comparison to objects and pages which that test case is refferring to